# AVAssetWriter complains that input from BlackMagic intensity is compressed and therefore can't be encoded

Tags: avfoundation, avcapturesession

I'm trying to build something that captures a video feed on a Mac in real time and writes out pre-segmented mp4 chunks. It's working for some cameras but not others.

The setup is as follows.

An `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` has a `AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate`.

```
dispatch_queue_t sampleQueue = dispatch_queue_create("samples", NULL);
[videoOutput setSampleBufferDelegate: delegate queue: sampleQueue];
```

The output is also involved in an `AVCaptureSession` which saves to a file and displays a preview, and that all works fine.

In the delegate, I have an `AVAssetWriterInput`. It's set up like this:

```
NSDictionary
    *videoFormat = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        // Format options
        AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoCodecKey,// h264
        [NSNumber numberWithInt: width], AVVideoWidthKey,
        [NSNumber numberWithInt: height], AVVideoHeightKey,
        // Encoder options
        [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
            [NSNumber numberWithInt: theQuality*1024], AVVideoAverageBitRateKey,// 256kbps
            [NSNumber numberWithInt: 30], AVVideoMaxKeyFrameIntervalKey,// write at least one keyframe every 30 frames
        nil], AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey,
    nil],
 video = [[AVAssetWriterInput assetWriterInputWithMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo outputSettings: videoFormat] retain];
[video setExpectsMediaDataInRealTime: YES];
```

There's a way to write to a file with this delegate:

```
writer = [[AVAssetWriter assetWriterWithURL: url fileType: AVFileTypeMPEG4 error: &error] retain];
[writer setShouldOptimizeForNetworkUse: YES];
[writer addInput: video];
```

Now inside the `captureData` callback method in the delegate, wherein I'm handled buffers of sampled data, I do this:

```
   if([video isReadyForMoreMediaData])
        [video appendSampleBuffer: sampleBuffer];
```

Great! This is working for my facetime camera. Now I plug in a BlackMagic Intensity and use that.

On this line:

```
        [video appendSampleBuffer: sampleBuffer];
```

I get this error:

```
*** -[AVAssetWriterInput appendSampleBuffer:] Input buffer must be in an uncompressed format when outputSettings is not nil
```

I have played around with the `videoOutput` settings, to no avail. The docs seem to mention that this is the thing that can't be compressed. Things like:

```
// not all at the same time, of course.
videoOutput.videoSettings = nil;
videoOutput.videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"avc1" forKey:AVVideoCodecKey];
```

The best part is that if I disable all of the encoding stuff on the output, it tells me that pass-through encoding isn't supported. Sweet.

Fortunately, googling this error message results in zero hits. If anyone can point me to the solution here, I'd love to know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Were you able to get to the bottom of this?

Comment: No. This was years ago, but if memory serves, I just set up a more 'normal' video stream and used ffmpeg to do the weirder parts. But even that didn't work--a fairly straightforward stream to disk ends up with audio well out of sync with the video. BlackMagic support never helped me out and eventually I gave up on the intensity. See https://github.com/bhuga/blackmagic-intensity-issue-demo/blob/master/blackmagic%20audio%20sync%20issue%20demonstration/main.m

Comment: @BK For your `AVAssetReaderTrackOutput` settings, do not pass nil, just create a `AVVideoSettingsUncompressed` and assign the Width and Height to the AVAssetTrack NaturalSize Width and Height and you will have an uncompressed buffer to feed your `AVAssetWriterInput`

Answer (score 0):

When the sampleBuffer codec is not uncompressed; i.e the codec is not yuvs or 2vuy or RGB then the output settings is expected to be nil. THen it will not transcode the sample buffer as it is already compressed.